# show recent records only

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a requirement to show most recent records when user selects the option to view most recent records. I have 3 different tables from which I take data and display on the screen.

Below are the sample tables created.

```
Create table one(sealID integer,product_ser_num varchar2(20),create_time timestamp,status varchar2(10));


create table two(transID integer,formatID integer, formatStatus varchar,ctimeStamp timestamp,sealID integer);

create table three(transID integer,fieldStatus varchar,fieldValue varchar,exctype varchar);
```

I'm joining above 3 tables and showing the results in a single screen. I want to display the most recent records based on the timestamp. 
Please find the sample data on the screen taken from 3 different tables.

```
ProductSerialNumber  formatID formatStatus  fieldStatus TimeStamp
 ASD100               100       P               P        2015-09-03 10:30:22
 ASD100               200       p               P        2015-09-03 10:30:22
 ASD100               100       p               P        2015-09-03 10:22:11
 ASD100               200       p               P        2015-09-03 10:22:11
```

I want to display the most recent records from the above shown table which should return first 2 rows as they are the recent records when checked with the timestamp column.

Please suggest what changes to be done to the below query to show most recent records.

```
SELECT transId,product_ser_num,status, to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') timestamp, 
                      cnt   
                     FROM (SELECT one.*,
                  row_number() over(ORDER BY 
                  CASE             
                  WHEN :orderDirection like '%asc%' THEN
                   CASE
                      WHEN :orderBy='product_ser_num' THEN product_ser_num,
                      WHEN :orderBy='status' THEN status  
                      WHEN :orderBy='timestamp' THEN to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                          ELSE to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                   END
                              END ASC,   
                                  CASE  
                    WHEN :orderDirection like '%desc%' THEN  
                    CASE 
                    WHEN :orderBy='product_ser_num' THEN product_ser_num, 
                                    WHEN :orderBy='status' THEN status 
                                    WHEN :orderBy='timestamp' THEN to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                                    ELSE to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
                                  END          
                               END DESC , transId ASC) line_number 
                               FROM (select one_inner.*, COUNT(1) OVER() cnt 
                  from (select two_tran.transaction_id,
                                  one_res.product_serial_number productSerialNumber,
                                  one_res.status status,from one one_res
                                  left outer join two two_trans on two_trans.sealID = one_res.sealID
                                  left outer join three three_flds on two_tran.transID = three_flds.transID and (three_flds.fieldStatus = 'P')
```

Comment: Always post your Oracle database version up to 4 decimal places. And please post sample data, don't post images, it is not at all helpful. Please post the create and insert statements, and post the desired output.

Comment: oracle10g is the version used. I thought it would give clear picture of the tables structure when images are seen. Requirement is to display most recent records. @lalith kumar B

Comment: It is difficult to see the images, also, it is impossible to copy the text from the images. You could prepare a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or post the create and insert statements in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are looking for a **Top-n** query as your topic title suggests.

It seems like you want to display the data in a customized order, as you have shown in the first image. You want the set of three rows to be grouped together on the basis of `timestamp`.

I have prepared a small test case to demonstrate the custom order of the rows:

```
SQL> WITH DATA(ID, num, datetime) AS(
  2  SELECT 10, 1001, SYSDATE     FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 10, 6009, SYSDATE     FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 10, 3951, SYSDATE     FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 10, 1001, SYSDATE -1  FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 10, 6009, SYSDATE -1  FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 10, 3951, SYSDATE -1  FROM dual
  8  )
  9  SELECT ID,
 10    num,
 11    TO_CHAR(DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') TIMESTAMP
 12  FROM
 13    (SELECT t.*,
 14      row_number() OVER(ORDER BY DATETIME DESC,
 15      CASE num
 16        WHEN 1001
 17        THEN 1
 18        WHEN 6009
 19        THEN 2
 20        WHEN 3951
 21        THEN 3
 22      END, num) rn
 23    FROM DATA t
 24    );

        ID        NUM TIMESTAMP
---------- ---------- -------------------
        10       1001 2015-09-04 11:04:48
        10       6009 2015-09-04 11:04:48
        10       3951 2015-09-04 11:04:48
        10       1001 2015-09-03 11:04:48
        10       6009 2015-09-03 11:04:48
        10       3951 2015-09-03 11:04:48

6 rows selected.
```

Now, you can see that for the same **ID** `10`, the **NUM** values are grouped and also in a custom order.

Comment: I don't want to customized order or group together based on time stamp. I already written logic to show records in descending order.  My only requirement is to just show most recent records instead of displaying all the records. And because my database query is too big with joins and nested queries, I was not sure how to proceed and in which block I need to give condition to achieve this. Please suggest, appreciate ur help , thanks.@lalit Kumasi B

Comment: @scrit Your query is too big to investigate just by looking at it. Can you make it precise to the exact requirement and post sample data just like I posted using WITH clause.

Comment: Please see the modified code. I made it simple and added the DB queries. Please suggest. thanks.

Comment: @scrit Ok. But you need to give the table data also, at least few insert statements for the three tables. That should be enough to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This query seems very large and complex, so this may be oversimplifying things:

Add a clause to the end `limit 3` ?

Comment: it's not always 3records.please read the question.its based on time stamp.please see the image1and read below content . @collin Driscoll

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need to do is:

```
select 
    max(timestamp), engine_serial_number, formatID
from
<
joins here
>
group by engine_serial_number, formatID
```

This will basically give you the lines you want, but not all metadata.

Hence, you will just have to `re-join` all this with the main join to get the rest of the info (join on all three columns, `engine serial number`, `formatID AND timestamp`).

That should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PS - you might wanna use the id column instead of timestamp for better performance. You just have to make sure higher timestamp is certain to mean higher id (it usually should).

Comment: But with ID column how can I know how many records should it return based on the timestamp. As my requirement is to return the most recent records which i'm thinking I need to check with timestamp. Please suggest. @Mihai Ovidiu Drăgoi

Comment: Use timestamp, see what it returns. Then use id as i suggested. There should be no difference. Sorry for the late response, I'm on holiday.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a precise answer, because your query is incomplete.  But I'll give you the general idea, and you can tweak it into your query.

One way to accomplish what you want is by using the `dense_rank()` analytical function to number your rows by timestamp in descending order (You could use `rank()` too in this case, it doesn't actually matter). All rows with the same timestamp will be assigned the same "rank", so you can then filter by rank to only get the most recent records.

Try to adjust your query to something like this:

```
select ...
  from (select ...,
               dense_rank() over (order by timestamp desc) as timestamp_rank
          from ...)
 where timestamp_rank = 1
 ...
```

I suspect that with a better understanding of your data model and query, there would probably be a better solution.  But based on the information provided, I think that the above should yield the results you are looking for.

Comment: Its not about showing 2 rows...Please see the timestamp column in the sample data shown. It should return most recent records as first 2 records are on the same time and they are the most recent records it should return those two rows. So if there are n number of records on the same timestamp then my query should return n number of records if they are the latest records. Thanks. @sstan

Comment: @scrit: does your requirement change based on the values for `:orderBy` and `:orderDirection`?  Or you always want this by timestamp?  Also, please do fix your posted query.  It is incomplete at the moment.

Comment: I always want to return the most recent record data which can be get using timestamp column from table one. Please suggest..thanks. I will try to fix my posted query . @sstan.

Comment: I edited my answer with a different option that seems more aligned with what you are asking.